# How to display values of a sequence in Maple 12

Tags: maple

I want your help to arrange the values of a sequence or function in a tabular form automatically by giving the "seq" command in maple 12.

e.g. $f(n)=n^2$

$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|}
 \hline n&f(n)\\ \hline0 & 0\\ \hline
 1 & 1\\ \hline
 2&4\\ \hline
3&9\\ \hline
\vdots&\vdots\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seq command alone doesn't do it, but you can try something like this:

```
> chart:= proc (head::list, vals::list)   
      Matrix([head, seq(eval(subs(head[1] = vals[i],head)),
         i = 1 .. nops(vals))])
     end proc;
```

Then, for example:

```
> chart([x,x^2],[$0..5]);
```

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} x&{x}^{2}\\ 0&0\\ 1&1\\ 2&4\\ 3&9\\ 4
&16\\ 5&25\end {array} \right] 
$$

Comment: Thank you sir. This program works upto $n=8$ in maple 12. I want to have the sequence upto $\infty$.

Comment: > interface(rtablesize=infinity);

Comment: Thank you sir, Now I want to plot those data points in maple. I don't know the maple code.

Comment: plot(%[2..-1,..],style=point);

Comment: If there is discontinuity at the beginning e.g$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
 \hline n&f(n)&g(n)&\cdots\\ \hline0 & 2&1&\cdots\\ \hline
 1 & 1&1&\cdots\\ \hline
 2&4&8&\cdots\\ \hline
3&9&27&\cdots\\ \hline
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
How to show it in tabular form and the plot in maple?